# XMLHttpRequest does not attach Authorization header in react native

Tags: android, react-native, xmlhttprequest, authorization

I am trying to open a server-sent-events connection on android in react native using `XMLHttpRequest`. My server does not see the attached authorization header. Any other headers that I attach to the request make it through. Here is my source code:

```
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("GET", "mydomain.com", true);

            this._xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream");
            this._xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            this._xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            this._xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", `Bearer: ${this.authorizationToken}`);
```

The value of the authorizationToken exists at runtime and is a normal jwt token. Using curl, I can successfully connect to my SSE server. However, it seems that the authorization token is stripped out of the request in react native. Is there a reason why this specific header is blocked? If I change the header key to `authToken` it is passed as expected. A hint may be related to this working on a localhost domain but not on production (real) domains. No fetch, no axios, I need to use XMLHttpRequest so I can establish a server-sent-events connection. Downstream shared code expects the presence of the authorization header. Here is what my server sees:

```
Request:  {
  url: '/testuser',
  body: {},
  params: {},
  headers: {
    host: 'mydomain.com',
    deviceid: 'mydeviceid',
    accept: 'text/event-stream',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
    'user-agent': 'okhttp/4.9.2',
    'x-forwarded-for': '',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
    'x-envoy-external-address': '',
    'x-request-id': '',
    'x-envoy-attempt-count': '1',
    'x-forwarded-client-cert': '',
    'x-b3-spanid': '',
    'x-b3-parentspanid': '',
    'x-b3-sampled': '0'
  }
}
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Tried to make an XMLHttpRequest with an authorization header, and the header was stripped out before reaching the server.

Answer (score 0):

tried this one and it's working fine. try to remove true from open method

const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
    Http.open("GET", url)
    Http.setRequestHeader('authorization', `Bearer: ehwrwhrkjewhgrkjewhregwjwgrjwgrjerjeg`)
    Http.send();
    console.log("Http =>>>>", Http)
```

output:-

```
{
    "DONE": 4,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
    "LOADING": 3,
    "OPENED": 1,
    "UNSENT": 0,
    "_aborted": false,
    "_cachedResponse": undefined,
    "_hasError": false,
    "_headers": {
        "authorization": "Bearer: ehwrwhrkjewhgrkjewhregwjwgrjwgrjerjeg"
    },
    "_incrementalEvents": true,
    "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {},
    "_method": "GET",
    "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
    "_performanceLogger": {
        "_closed": false,
        "_extras": {},
        "_pointExtras": {},
        "_points": {
            "initializeCore_end": 8665333.465721,
            "initializeCore_start": 8665252.249148
        },
        "_timespans": {
            "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://localhost:8081/symbolicate": [Object],
            "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2": [Object]
        }
    },
    "_requestId": null,
    "_response": "",
    "_responseType": "",
    "_sent": true,
    "_subscriptions": [{
        "context": undefined,
        "listener": [Function anonymous],
        "remove": [Function remove]
    }, {
        "context": undefined,
        "listener": [Function anonymous],
        "remove": [Function remove]
    }, {
        "context": undefined,
        "listener": [Function anonymous],
        "remove": [Function remove]
    }, {
        "context": undefined,
        "listener": [Function anonymous],
        "remove": [Function remove]
    }, {
        "context": undefined,
        "listener": [Function anonymous],
        "remove": [Function remove]
    }, {
        "context": undefined,
        "listener": [Function anonymous],
        "remove": [Function remove]
    }],
    "_timedOut": false,
    "_trackingName": "unknown",
    "_url": "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
    "readyState": 1,
    "responseHeaders": undefined,
    "status": 0,
    "timeout": 0,
    "upload": {},
    "withCredentials": true
}
```

Comment: I tried removing true but to no avail. The header does exist in the event source object when logged; however, I think when you open the connection the header is stripped out and the downstream server does not see it. I never had an issue with the actual event source object missing the header, but downstream server cannot see it. Pretty strange. On top of this, on android, `onreadystatechange` is not firing properly. I dug a little online and saw that this may be due to Flipper and I need to disable it; however, I don't think this is possible with the expo managed workflow.